# Android: Best practice handling resources for WVGA screens

Tags: android, resources, screen-density

I'm wondering what's the best practice dealing with resources for WVGA screens.

I've tried the resource structure before:

```
/values-sw320dp/dimens.xml (for WVGA)
/values/dimens.xml (for others)
```

However, all other 720p, 1080p devices ran into sw320dp resources since their SWs (Smallest Width) are 360dp, which >= 320dp.

Thus, in my current project, I use the following resource structure:

```
values/dimens.xml
values-sw320dp/dimens.xml
values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
```

However it's a bit annoying to maintain 3 XMLs.
So my questions are:

- Is it safe to remove default /values folder?
- Is there a simpler way
  to have only 2 XMLs-- one for WVGA and one for others?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If your goal is to have only 2 dimens.xml files, then just keep one under _/values-sw320dp/_ and one under _/values_

Comment: Just like i said at the beginning, once I created values-sw320dp/ all other devices will pick /values-sw320dp instead of /values...

Comment: I see, well realistically there are few (no?) reasonably new devices with width <320dp, so you can turn it around and have /values-sw360dp/ for all other devices and /values/ for 320dp devices.

Comment: It works! Thanks Kai :D